# Why can't I add a cluster to ArgoCD?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I have two contexts:

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME       CLUSTER    AUTHINFO         NAMESPACE
          k8s-nt     k8s-nt     k9s-nt-admin     default
*         k8s-pred   k8s-pred   k9s-pred-admin   default
```

In ArgoCD I am trying to add a cluster `k8s-pred` or `k8s-nt`:

```
argocd@argocd-server-54f776b458-mjlwc:~$ argocd cluster add k8s-pred
FATA[0000] Context k8s-pred does not exist in kubeconfig 
argocd@argocd-server-54f776b458-mjlwc:~$ argocd cluster add k8s-nt  
FATA[0000] Context k8s-nt does not exist in kubeconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>  kubectl config view # check the configuration of k8s context and cluster
>  kubectl config use-context k8s-nt

> argocd login server 
  WARNING: server is not configured with TLS. Proceed (y/n)? y
  Username:
  password:
> argocd cluster add k8s-pred
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**